# Crystal Report not working with .net framework 4.0 based computer with windows xp OS

Tags: c#, ms-access, crystal-reports, .net-framework-version

I am building Windows Form application with crystal report in C# .
I am using VS2017 community studio for its development. I use MS access Database.

Now when i select .net FW above 4.6 , my sw works well in windows 7(32 or 64 bit) PC, also crystal report which i used for reporting of entered Data works well. there i have no issue.

But as my customer have PC with Windows XP OS , supporting .net FW 4.0, I changed setting of project to this FW. Hence, i face problem that crystal report gives exception, only report viewer opens not any entered data.

Can anyone solve this issue, what steps should i follow to make this crystal to work for Windows XP PC with .net FW 4 or below without error.

thanks in advance .
kp.

Comment: "gives exception": which exception?

Comment: It shows that--- "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application." also in details section message----Exception Text is----"CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsEcxeption: Load report failed......"

Answer (score 1):

Service Pack 26 and above no longer support .Net Framework 3.5 (and recommend upgrading to 4.5.2 or above).
So, given that you need to support XP as OS, consider dropping back to SP 25 or earlier.